# x and y in sympy's Line.equation() behave strange

Tags: python, sympy

Why are `myLe` and `myEq` different in the code below？They look equal when printed out.

I need `myLe-myEq` to be zero.

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
myLe=Line(Point(2,3), Point(3,5)).equation()
myEq=-2*x + y + 1
print("#",type(x-x ),x-x )
print("#",type(myLe),myLe)
print("#",type(myEq),myEq)
print("#",type(myLe-myEq),myLe-myEq)
# <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Zero'> 0
# <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -2*x + y + 1
# <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -2*x + y + 1
# <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -2*x + 2*x - y + y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `myLe=Line(Point(2,3), Point(3,5)).equation()`, sympy uses internal variables which to the outside have names x and y, but are different internal variables than the ones you declared before.

You can force sympy to use the same internal variables by writing `Line(Point(2, 3), Point(3, 5)).equation(x=x, y=y)`.

```py
from sympy import *

var('x y')
myLe = Line(Point(2, 3), Point(3, 5)).equation(x=x, y=y)
myEq = -2 * x + y + 1
print("#", type(x - x), x - x)
print("#", type(myLe), myLe)
print("#", type(myEq), myEq)
print("#", type((myLe - myEq)), myLe - myEq)
# <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Zero'> 0
# <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -2*x + y + 1
# <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -2*x + y + 1
# <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Zero'> 0
```

Depending on your application, you might even want to use different names for different equations.

```py
var('x1 y1')
myLe = Line(Point(2, 3), Point(3, 5)).equation(x=x1, y=y1)
print("#", myLe)
# -2*x1 + y1 + 1
```